# iterate through xsd xml file

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xmlreader

I am trying to iterate through an xsd file i have been given.

It is has hundreds of these complex type elements and I am trying to iterate through each and end up with an array as seen below.

```
 <xs:complexType name="UserAccessDeviceFileGetListRequest">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="core:OCIRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="userId" type="UserId"/>
      <xs:element name="accessDevice" type="AccessDevice"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

```
<xs:complexType name="UserAccessDeviceFileModifyRequest">
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="core:OCIRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="userId" type="UserId"/>
      <xs:element name="accessDevice" type="AccessDevice"/>
      <xs:element name="fileFormat" type="DeviceManagementFileFormat"/>
      <xs:element name="uploadFile" type="FileResource"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

```
 Array
 (
     [UserAccessDeviceFileGetListRequest] => Array
                                              ( [0] => "userId"
                                                [1] => "accessDevice"
                                              )
     [UserAccessDeviceFileModifyRequest] = > Array
                                              ( [0] => "userId"
                                                [1] => "accessDevice"
                                                [2] => "fileFormat"
                                                [3] => "uploadFile"
                                              )
    )
```

I have tried using xmlreader and I can get the complexType's names but cant get any deeper to get the element names...

```
  $xsdstring = "file.xsd";
 $t = new XMLREADER();
 $t->open($xsdstring);

 while($t->read())
 {
     if ($t->name === "xs:complexType")
            {
                    echo "-->" . $t->getAttribute('name') . "\n";
            }
 }
```

Results with a list of all the complexType name attributes...

```
-->UserAccessDeviceFileGetListRequest
-->UserAccessDeviceFileModifyRequest
```

how can i get the children too?

Comment: In your code snippet you only read xs:complexType and access the name attribute. You need to get the xs:sequence child elements too.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to work with a representation of the compiled schema, such as Saxon's SCM format (which is an XML vocabulary, but much easier to process than raw XSD, because it's a single file, all the defaults are expanded, etc).

Doing an XSLT transformation from the SCM file to your desired output would be very straightforward.

You're making life much more difficult for yourself by using low-level procedural coding rather than a language like XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: The Saxon's stuff looks to be java based, and nothing i am doing is in java.  This is a whole new world to me so you talked a bit above my head, but I am going to read up on this stuff.  I appreciate the direction.

Comment: You can generate an SCM file with a simple command line call, and you can transform the resulting file with XSLT, so you don't actually need to write any Java, though you do need to have Java installed.